# Why does Google not show the most popular answer as the default?

Tags: discussion, search, google

I google `mac disable shortcuts`.

Then Google shows me the answer form Stack Overflow in a special frame. I go by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719135/how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-mac-os-x), and see that actually the other answer is most voted.

Is that because of rating of author made sense? Or because it is the first answer? Or other reasons? Is that logic done by Google?

[image]

Comment: You should ask Google.

Comment: basically because google is google, and stackoverflow is stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is out of control of Stack Overflow. This is from the *About this result* URL:

> **How can I mark my page as a featured snippet?**
>
> You can't. Google programmatically determines that a page contains a
>   likely answer to the user's question, and displays the result as a
>   featured snippet.

You can click the *Feedback* link if you have a suggestion for Google.

Comment: thank you, just was needed to know if SO did something about that, like through markup for google robots